# Save image to java project path using multipart

Tags: java, angularjs, eclipse, spring

Trying to save image in project path directly. Image is directly uploading from UI which is build on Angularjs. I want to save the image to a folder, in the project in eclipse but it is throwing exception. I am using MutipartFile interface of spring framework

Project Structure

```
web
|
 src
   |
    main
       |
        webapp
             |
              app
                |
                 images
```

Code

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/attachmentPath", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Response attachmentPath(Attachment attachment , @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
String orgName = file.getOriginalFilename();
String filePath = "/images/"+orgName;
        File dest = new File(filePath);
        try { file.transferTo(dest); }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) 
        { e.printStackTrace();}
```

Exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: img\images\users\TestCopy1.jpg (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: which exception ? provide stack trace ?

Comment: @javaguy - Added now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception says `filePath` variable is NOT resolved to a complete folder path, so you need to fix your `filePath` variable to resolve to a complete absolute path url like below (for example).

The web application folder absolute path can be retrived as `request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath()`

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/attachmentPath", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response attachmentPath(HttpServletRequest request, Attachment attachment , @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
    String orgName = file.getOriginalFilename();
    String absolutePathToImages = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/");
    String filePath = absolutePathToImages + orgName;
    File dest = new File(filePath);
    //check destination exists, if not create it
    if(!dest.exists())
    {
       new File(dest).mkdir();
    }
    try { 
       file.transferTo(dest); 
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e) 
    { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I know about this solution and I had already implemented it but what I am asking is to save the file directly in the project with out absolute path. Suppose if I want to retrieve one image from the same folder, I can retrieve it like this - String rootDir = "images\\example.jpg". In the same way I want to save with out absolute path. I hope I am able to describe my problem.

Comment: The issue is partially solved. Getting absolute path of my workspace. My code is in different folder. When I try locate the folder, it is giving me the workspace location not the code location where the code resides. Can we solve this as well ?

Comment: G:\myProj\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\web\img

Answer (score 0):

Your ***String*** `filePath =` ... has no **session** nor **ServletContext** . This is throwing the `FileNotFoundException` exception. .

Here is how I implemented my app to save the file directly in the project. You can change the path (root directory) according to your accordingingly.

My Pojo class Product:

```
public class Product implements Serializable{

...

@JsonIgnore 
    private MultipartFile  productImage;

//getters setters

@XmlTransient  
    public MultipartFile getProductImage() {
        return productImage;
    }

    public void setProductImage(MultipartFile productImage) {
        this.productImage = productImage;
    }
...

}
```

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processAddNewProductForm(@ModelAttribute("newProduct") @Valid Product productToBeAdded, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {   

        MultipartFile productImage = productToBeAdded.getProductImage();
        String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

            if (productImage!=null && !productImage.isEmpty()) {
               try {

                productImage.transferTo(new File(rootDirectory+"resources\\images\\"+productToBeAdded.getProductId() + ".png"));
               } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Product Image saving failed", e);
           }
           }


       //   productService.addProduct(productToBeAdded); 
        return "redirect:/products";
    }
```

Comment: The issue is partially solved. Getting absolute path of my workspace. My code is in different folder. When I try locate the folder, it is giving me the workspace location not the code location where the code resides. Can we solve this as well ?

Comment: G:\myProj\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\web\img